# How to Turn Off Binary XML Views in Eclipse (Android)

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, binary

Up until recently everything has been working fine in Eclipse and when I double clicked an xml file it would just pop up and I could edit it.

Now what is happening when I double click or click Open from the drop down menu I notice that my xml files have been converted to binary and I have to right click and view as binary xml and the layout view is no longer available.

Please let me know how to change this back and/or how it happened in the first place.

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem.  After a fresh install of eclipse everything returned to normal.  It appears that for some reason after the auto update came through it was causing a lot of interface lag and in turn slowing down the loading and opening of projects.  If you attempt to view a xml file that has not been parsed by Eclipse it will only allow you to view it in binary format which of course using the binary xml editor packed with Eclipse is fine but removes the ability to open by double clicking and requires a right click "Open As..."

Thanks for your attempts to answer this question for me and sorry if you were not understanding exactly what was happening.

P.S.  Hopefully if you have found this post with a similar search that it has helped you understand and solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you try `Open With->Android Layout Editor` ?

Comment: I get the cannot be viewed message.  It's storing it in binary for some reason.  I have been fiddling around with it a bit and I am thinking maybe the resources are not completely loaded when I am trying to pull them up.  Perhaps it just gets slower the more projects you have in your work space?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by it being stored in binary?  Is this only when you use the Open action from the File menu?  If so, does it work properly if the file is in the workspace?

Comment: the exact error I get when I double click the XML file from package explorer is ... "Could not open the editor: Android XML Editor Error" ... the only way I can view it is to right click and "Open With" Android Binary XML Editor.